# adding/removing a cell from grouped section in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to add/remove cells to my grouped table dynamically during runtime.  This is my first app that I have ever made, and while I have tried many other people's suggestions, I am still not getting it to work.  Here is my code that I am using:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [lblName setText:[intervalArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
```

Comment: Where's the code where you're adding/removing cells?

Comment: side note: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: may return nil; you need to check for that and allocate a new UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the `array` (will need to be an `NSMutableArray`) that is being used as the datasource for the `UITableView`.  Then you can

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

To reload the `tableview`

This is a good guide for dealing with updating TableView rows:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html